# Error during git push with high number of files

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a git repository on AzureDevops, on premise.

In my Azure Pipeline I have a step who changes the assembly info version (.NET), so I have around 250 files changes. Then my pipeline tries to commit and push these changes. The `git push` command gives me this error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 401
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I added this step recently. I already have a `git push` command to push a commit with a single file changed, and It worked. It is not an authentication problem.

In the "build machine" I have installed Git version 2.7.2 for windows.

What I've tried so far:

1. I tried to split the commit in 4 small commit and performs 4 push. It works.
2. On my pc I am able to complete the `git push` successfully.
3. I tried to increse the buffer size with this command `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`. Same error.
4. I tried to perform those operations with my credentials, (same credentials I used to try on my pc)... same error.

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE:**

As Omer suggests, I tried to update Git version to 2.27.0. Error is still there.

I check the commits size and it is under the `postBuffer` size I set.

I checked also the `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` command has been applied successfully.
Here I add additional informations that may be interesting:

AzureDevops pipeline checkout a detached head, so the full push command I use is:

> git push http://user:pwd@tfs_address/_git/MyGitRepos HEAD:master

To be honest, in my pc I tried to perform a normal `git push` operation. Is there something wrong in that command related to the bad git push's operation result?

Comment: 2.7.2 is rather old, maybe updating would help? What remote are you trying to push to? How big is the push? Maybe 525288000 is not enough, try increasing it. Another alternative is to set an SSH remote rather than an HTTP/S remote which I believe does not have this limitation. Did you make sure that the `git config` command actually applied?

Comment: @Omer I tried what you suggest, I updated the question with additional informations. But why should I try SSH? Why would SSH succeed and HTTP doesn't? Thank you.

Comment: With regard to SSH, the http.postBuffer is a limitation for the HTTP protocol between the git client and the remote. I believe that if you use an `ssh://...` remote, this problem would disappear, because the SSH protocol would be used instead of HTTP, and it won't have this limitation. How did you "check the commit size"? At the end of the day, the "commit size" and " the size of what is actually being sent over the HTTP connection, including overheard" could be very different. Try to use Wireshark and follow the TCP stream of the HTTP connection - how much data is sent in reality?

Comment: Firstly, make sure you could push it on agent machine manually. Secondly, change your build agent's account (log on as) to your account, then restart this service.